# Group sorted set with same index

Tags: swift

Let say we have a sorted array like:

```
let sortedArray = [(A, 0), (B, 1), (C, 1), (D, 2), (E, 2), (F, 2)]
```

How can I group them with the same second parameter in tuple like:

```
let result = [
     ([A], 0), 
     ([B, C], 1), 
     ([D, E, F], 2)
]
```

`[B, C]` and `[D, E, F]` inherit the same order from the sorted array.

Edit:

I have these code on my playground trying to run

```
let origin: [(String, Int)] = [("0", 0), ("1", 1), ("2", 1), ("2", 2), ("3", 2)]
if let last = origin.last {
    let array = Array<([String], Int)>.init(repeating: ([], 0), count: last.1)

    for (index, ele) in origin.enumerated() {
        var b = array[index] as? ([String], Int)
        b?.0.append(ele.0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce(into:)` combined with `index(where:)` method. If you find the index of the integer append a new string to the array otherwise append a new tuple element with a single string array and the corresponding integer:

```
let sortedArray:[(string: String, integer: Int)] = [("A", 0), ("B", 1), ("C", 1), ("D", 2), ("E", 2), ("F", 2)]
let grouped = sortedArray.reduce(into: [(strings:[String], integer: Int)]()) { partial, tuple in

    if let index = partial.index(where: {$0.integer == tuple.integer }) {
        partial[index].strings.append(tuple.string)
    } else {
        partial.append(([tuple.string], tuple.integer))
    }
}


print(grouped)
```

This will print:

> [(strings: ["A"], integer: 0), (strings: ["B", "C"], integer: 1), (strings: ["D", "E", "F"], integer: 2)]

If you don't want to name your tuple elements:

```
let sortedArray = [("A", 0), ("B", 1), ("C", 1), ("D", 2), ("E", 2), ("F", 2)]
let grouped = sortedArray.reduce(into: [([String],Int)]()) { partial, tuple in
    if let index = partial.index(where: {$0.1 == tuple.1 }) {
        partial[index].0.append(tuple.0)
    } else {
        partial.append(([tuple.0], tuple.1))
    }
}
```